# click on svg element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a simple HTML page which contains an svg image embedded as an object. I would like to use javascript to make elements from within that svg clickable.

Upon clicking on a particular element of the svg (which has `id='node1'`) I would like to execute the function `testFunc`

I tried to create an event listener but to no luck. There doesn't seem to be a contentDocument for the object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script>
      function testFunc()
      {
      alert("test")
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="graph-test.svg" id="flow">
       fallback here
      </object>
    </div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var svgObject = document.getElementById('flow').contentDocument;
      var node1 = svgObject.getElementById('node1');
      node1.addEventListener("click", testFunc)
    });
  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">


<svg width="407pt" height="360pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 406.71 360.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 356)">
<title>%3</title>
<polygon fill="#ffffff" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-356 402.7104,-356 402.7104,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- A -->
<g id="node1" class="node">
<title>A</title>
<polygon fill="#666699" stroke="#666699" points="350.0797,-352 130.7514,-352 130.7514,-316 350.0797,-316 350.0797,-352"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="240.4155" y="-336.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">It&#39;s annoying that you are </text>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="240.4155" y="-322.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff"> enduring something that&#39;s annoying</text>
</g>
<!-- B -->
<g id="node2" class="node">
<title>B</title>
<polygon fill="#666699" stroke="#666699" points="168.7467,-194 .0844,-194 .0844,-158 168.7467,-158 168.7467,-194"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="84.4155" y="-178.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">Did you do something you </text>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="84.4155" y="-164.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff"> sohuld not have done?</text>
</g>
<!-- A&#45;&gt;B -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge">
<title>A&#45;&gt;B</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M169.3515,-315.8946C140.9836,-304.9901 110.8283,-288.0007 92.7729,-262 81.2401,-245.3921 79.5349,-222.4318 80.5057,-204.4125"/>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="84.0144,-204.4538 81.3619,-194.1964 77.0388,-203.8691 84.0144,-204.4538"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="153.2368" y="-250.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">If something == True</text>
</g>
<!-- L -->
<g id="node3" class="node">
<title>L</title>
<polygon fill="#666699" stroke="#666699" points="218.7194,-36 106.1116,-36 106.1116,0 218.7194,0 218.7194,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="162.4155" y="-13.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">Are you a human</text>
</g>
<!-- A&#45;&gt;L -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge">
<title>A&#45;&gt;L</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M239.9121,-315.702C238.2911,-274.3429 231.5128,-170.9534 203.4155,-90 197.8971,-74.1005 188.8589,-57.6949 180.6709,-44.5669"/>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="183.5451,-42.5656 175.1918,-36.0485 177.6578,-46.3523 183.5451,-42.5656"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="243.1914" y="-171.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">False</text>
</g>
<!-- C -->
<g id="node4" class="node">
<title>C</title>
<polygon fill="#666699" stroke="#666699" points="398.5063,-194 306.3248,-194 306.3248,-158 398.5063,-158 398.5063,-194"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="352.4155" y="-171.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">Are you a old</text>
</g>
<!-- A&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge">
<title>A&#45;&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M253.2634,-315.8754C272.9061,-288.1651 310.5217,-235.1002 333.3524,-202.8926"/>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="336.4449,-204.5822 339.3726,-194.3999 330.7341,-200.5341 336.4449,-204.5822"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="318.4707" y="-250.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Dunno</text>
</g>
<!-- B&#45;&gt;L -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge">
<title>B&#45;&gt;L</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M93.3631,-157.8754C106.926,-130.4019 132.7926,-78.0054 148.7295,-45.723"/>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="152.0437,-46.9161 153.332,-36.3999 145.7669,-43.8174 152.0437,-46.9161"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="160.2466" y="-92.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">MYLABEL</text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: put `id` on svg itself not on `g` tag

Comment: @meisam sorry not sure I understand. Do you mean within the svg file? That svg is auto generated so can't edit it really. Also I'm trying you have just one small part of the svg clickable rather than the whole svg

Comment: on line 5 your svg tag is there. just add `id-"someId"` to it an use it in your js. If you want to add click handler on  a small part of svg, make sure you are clicking on it correctly

Comment: This code should work for what you are trying to do. Are you sure there is an svg called graph-test.svg in the directory of your HTML page. I think there might be something wrong with how you referred to it in the object tag.

How exactly is the SVG generated?

Comment: [Your code works fine here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jouFusxr6c4Jp9XshgSB?p=preview).

Comment: @Kaiido @hektor-misplon that is strange. I can't get it to work at all on my computer. The svg does load on the page so it can find it. Additionally I just tested adding `  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var svgObject = document.getElementById('flow');
      alert(svgObject)
    });
  </script>` to see if it can get the 'flow' element and it alerts with "[object HTMLObjectElement]" but if I append .contentDocument I get "null"

Comment: And you are serving this page from what protocol? http:// or file://? If http:// is the svg hosted on the same domain than your html file?

Comment: @kalido Just opening up the file in chrome with file:// and the svg and html file are both in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

```
var svgObject = document.getElementById('flow').contentDocument;
```

returns an **XMLDocument** which is the root of your svg document. Unfortunately we aren't deep enough in it's hierarchy yet. We're interested in it's children. If you add a **.childNodes** you'll get **NodesList** - more or less an array - which contains two elements - whereas we're interested in the second one because it contains your actual svg data.
We can access it using:

```
var svgObject = document.getElementById('flow').contentDocument.childNodes[1];
```

Well that's it - now you can get a reference to your desired svg group using:

```
var node1 = svgObject.getElementById('node1');
```

Comment: The code that he posted should work for what he is trying to do. I think this returns an error because the file graph-test.svg is either not found or loaded incorrectly.

Comment: [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a method of the Document interface. Calling it from `.contentDocument` was correct.

Comment: hi your code looks good but define script at the end of the file ,when the whole page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Resources served from the `file://` protocol are considered Cross-Origin.
This means you won't be able to access the content of these resources.

Use a local server instead.